# GA4 and UA reason for incompatibility of metrics and dimensions data analyzation and ML

Tags: google-analytics

I am working on a machine-learning model and I want to analyze and incomporite GA4 and UA data. But i struggle with understanding structure of data in ga4 and UA as i have access to the data thru API or looker studio

What are the reasons for incompatibility of metrics and dimension? Is there any article which discusses the reasons?

I am aware of this site: https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/ but i am lacking an explanation, which would help me to get a broader picture.

There is no problem for me to get the metrics I want for the specific dimensions separately so i don't encounter any incompatibilities or limits and then join them afterwards on dimension in python, but i would like to know if this is a valid approach.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, If you're working with ETLed data, you need to know it better. [This](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11986666?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) can be useful.

It's still not good enough since it doesn't imply that you're looking at raw data. It only gives barely enough clarity and high-level detail for someone who's using their interface and doesn't care much about understanding the mechanics behind dimensions and metrics. But in conjunction with just how the raw data looks, it should be helpful.

Now, if you have the resources to ETL the data and do some ML on it, you must have people who make sure your front-end tracking data is not garbage. Either front-end analysts or tracking specialists. They should be able to either explain the abnormalities that the comparison reference does not or debug them further. Those abnormalities may be caused by tracking bugs or features that they're aware of or can go check on the site/app.

Well and there also are custom dimensions. Hit-level metrics for them should be exactly equal across the platforms. Inequalities there indicate tracking bugs, so that could be a good point of reference for assessing other hit-level discrepancies.

Ah, you also should expect the client ids to coincide between UA and GA4, if it's implemented correctly. That should allow for effortless data joins. Make sure you have fake session IDs generated for UA as a CD since it doesn't offer a session id in the exports, but still generates sessions. That will allow much simpler sessions debugging in data.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to get some more independent variables for the training. There is no need for me to get granual information for the model as I think aggregation of data would suit me fine. But due to the situation of UA being discontinued, it does not make much sense to train on UA data anymore. And now I am in this situation trying to convert from UA format to GA4 but from initial look i won't be able to do it as linear models trained on 200 000 pairs of UA to GA4 entries give me crap result. but thats theme for another SO question

Comment: it's definitely possible to sync UA with GA4, but a lot of data adjustments will need to be done.